# i18n text update language didn't work on script

Tags: vue.js, vue-i18n

I'm working on multi-language i18n, I have prepared everything and tried to translate HTML text for example:

```html
<q-item-section>{{ $t('display') }}</q-item-section>
```

And it works fine but my problem now is with updating txt in script like I have section like that:

```html
<q-item-section >{{HideMore}}</q-item-section>
```

And into data (myscript) I have tried that:

```js
HideMore: this.$t('hide')
```

Ok now it shows me the txt but when I try to switch the language nothing actually happened (the txt didn't update).

Comment: How are you switching between the languages. Can you confirm if the switching actually succeeded?

Comment: yup I'm using drop List then get it data and change the value of locale language with drop data like `this.$i18n.locale = lang.value` and really when I'm tring to switching txt on my html like the first exemple it gives to me the correct string like if I use en-us : it result will be "HIDE ELEMENT" and when I use fr it will be "Masquer lélément" soo it works but when I tried to switch variable in code it will never changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know you can't use this (or any function) in the `data` object.

What I did when I encountered this issue is I placed it in a computed variable:

```js
computed: {
  breadcrumbs: function(){
    return [{
      text: this.$t('locations.titlePlural')
    }]
  },
},
```

**Edit:**

I discovered when you define the data property like this:

```js
data: function () {
  return {
    propName: this.someFunction()
  }
},
```

You are actually able to call `this` an by that you're able to call methods that return a value!

[Vue docs](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/data-option.html#_2-x-syntax)

Comment: Ah right, didn't see that coming. Alternatively though, you could also use the `t` function with imported `i18n` instance, like: `i18n.t('Hide')` (within the `data` option).

Comment: @YomS. I did not know that was possible, thanks for sharing!